# EmguCV: How to convert code working with pointers and step?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, emgucv

I'm trying to convert some code from an open source library written with OpenCV 1.0 to EmguCV C# in .NET.

Here is the problematic code:

```
float* ptr = rotatedEdges->data.fl;
int step = rotatedEdges->step / sizeof(float);

for(i = 0; i < _LOCAL_ROT_DIVS; ++i)
{
    reRowPtrs[i] = ptr + i*step;
}
```

I know that the `rotatedEdges` has a `Data` getter, but this returns a 2D array of float. In OpenCV, the `data` field in an 1D array of float (if my memory is correct).
So I was wondering what is the correct way of doing this loop so it does exactly the same thing?

Thanks!

***EDIT***

[Here is the page](http://code.google.com/p/cvaddon/source/browse/cvaddon_fast_sym/cvaddon_fast_sym_detect.cpp) with the code I'm trying to convert as asked in the comment.

Comment: What datatype is `rotatedEdges`?

Comment: it is created as an openCV matrix:  rotatedEdges = cvCreateMat(ROT_DIVS, IMG_DIAG, CV_32FC1);

Comment: Could you post the whole source code (or a link) so that we know what `ROT_DIVS`, `IMG_DIAG`, `_LOCAL_ROT_DIVS` and `reRowPtrs` are?

Comment: See updated question for the link

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in C# you want `reRowPtrs` to be a `float[][]` (jagged array). And you probably want `rotatedEdges` to be a `Matrix<float>`. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not even sure if reRowPtrs need to be a float[][] but yes, you understand me correctly!

Comment: I think you can just do a for loop and convert the `float[,]` from `rotatedEdges.Data` to a `float[][]`.

Or do you only want a `float[]` with the first element of each row? I get confused of all the pointers in the source code ;)

Comment: I'm not even sure what he's trying to do. The source code is very hard to understand and since it's an advanced algorithm, it's very difficult to make sense. I will try what you suggest.